# can maven compile multiple source folder to multiple target folder

Tags: maven-2

I am trying to change a ant project to maven project, here is the problem.
for example: I have two source folder.

```
-pom.xml    
-ejb
    -org
        -x
          -ejbclass1.java
-tpf
    -org
        -x
          -tpfclass1.java
```

now I want to generate class file under target folder like this:

```
ejb
   -classes
           -org
               -x
                 -ejbclass1.class
tpf
   -classes
           -org
               -x
                 -tpfclass1.class
```

is there any plugin can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two seperate maven prosjectst and bind them with one super project (maven projects can be chierarchical).

Your directory structure chould look like this:

```
master-pom.pom
  ejb {dir}
     ejb-pom.pom
     src {dir} 
     ....
  tpf {dir}
     tpf-pom.pom
     src {dir} 
     ...
```

use `<modules>` tag in master pom.

Compiling a master procject will compile both subprojects

here's a tutorial

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects